# Turning off companion gathering?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Ok so with all the new and fast respawning nodes in the Yavin 4 area's i have come to realize that my companion is slowing me down when i go on a gathering farm.

clicking the node makes him gather but there is always a delay, the player itself wont gather unless the companion is already gathering or not summoned.

So is there an option somewhere to turn off the companion gathering so that the player will always gather when clicking a node?

Comment: I don't know if there's an option, but Shift-Right clicking does it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Frank noted in the comments, you can `Shift + Right Click` to gather yourself.

However, you can also swap the controls (so that you gather on Right Click, and the companion uses Shift) via `Preferences -> Controls -> General`:

[image: screenshot]